# Angular iframe dynamisch: $sce: Cannot Read property of undefined

Tags: angularjs

I try to make a word combinator for keywords. After combining them I want to load dynamically google search requests into an iframe. Unfortunately I have some problems with $sce-service.

Errormessage:
`TypeError: Cannot read property 'trustAsUrl' of undefined`

```
Same error for $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(...);
```

My plunkr:
http://plnkr.co/edit/N2nzBVElPtegaPYUCXlz

Important part:

Controller.js

```
var keywordAppControllers = angular.module('keywordAppControllers', []);

keywordAppControllers.controller('KeywordCtrl', ['$scope','$sce',
  function ($scope) {
    $scope.myData = {};
    $scope.myData.previewUrl="";

    $scope.serpPreview = function(keyword, $sce, $scope) {
      previewUrl="https://www.google.de/search?q=" + encodeURIComponent(keyword);
      // previewUrl="https://www.google.de/search?q=" + keyword;
      console.log(previewUrl);
      trustedUrl = $sce.trustAsUrl('https://www.google.de/');
      console.log(trustedUrl);
      // $scope.myData.previewUrl = $sce.trustAsUrl('www.google.de/');
      // $scope.myData.previewUrl = $sce.trustAsUrl('https://www.google.de/');
      // $scope.myData.previewUrl = $sce.trustAsUrl('https://google.de/');
      // $scope.myData.previewUrl = $sce.trustAsUrl('//google.de/');
    };
    // create a blank object to hold our form information
    // $scope will allow this to pass between controller and view
    $scope.formData = {};
  }
]);
```

App.js:

```
var keywordApp = angular.module('keywordApp', [
  'keywordAppControllers'
]).config(function($sceDelegateProvider) {
   $sceDelegateProvider.resourceUrlWhitelist([
     // Allow same origin resource loads.
     'self',
     // Allow loading from our assets domain.  Notice the difference between * and **.
     'https://google.de/*',
     'http://google.de/*',
     'https://google.de/**',
     'http://google.de/**'
   ]);
 });
```

Comment: Controller.js, ln 4: `function ($scope) {` - i guess $sce is not injected?

Comment: So how do I inject it? But a diff. project I got an error if s.th. was not injected, this time there is no such error.

Comment: I added the $Sce on line 4. if I use it within the core function e.g. at line 11 it works but it still does not work in the subfunction. Any ideas who to inject it properly there?